# Customizing dispForm of creating a "standardview" - SP2013

Tags: 2013, newform, dispform

For every library there is a possibility for users to create their own view on documents (such as metadata filters). Because the "`/_layouts/15/ViewNew.aspx`" Form is kinda confusing for tons of users when they want to create a new view, I wanted to know if there is any way how I can customize it (editing `dispForm`).

I'm using SharePoint 2013 (In my company SharePoint Designer isn't allowed and I also don't have rights for editing `masterpage`).

Is there any way, how I can get into the dispForm of this page - for example changing sth in URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a server level page, you aren't going to be able to customize it in Designer anyway so you don't have to worry about that. And even if you could, it would be something that would affect every site so it wouldn't be wise to do so.

I think this is a training opportunity more than anything. It can be confusing at first, but think of the power you will be instilling in your user base to be able to create views to slice and dice the data they are working with to answer the questions they may have or gain insight into something.

Teach them to fish. We're talking about view configuration here, there isn't much that they can do, but the things they can do will make them self sufficient.